# C# '&' regex problem

Tags: c#, regex

i've got a problem with C# regular expression. There is an JSON string like this (it's from Google Insights page):

`{"name":"all categories","id":0,"prime":true,"children":[{"name":"arts \u0026 humanities","id":570,"prime":true,"children":[{"name":"books \u0026 literature","id":22, ...`

Now I want to write a regex to find, for example, `books \u0026 literature` -- but I can't. 
Neither `Regex.Match(html, "books & literature", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` nor `Regex.Match(html, "books \\u0026 literature", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` doesn't works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to use a JSON library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the string you're searching for has a literal `\`,  you need to have a literal backslash escaped in your regex, either by `@"books \\u0026 literature"` or `"books \\\\u0026 literature"`.

For example:

```
Regex.Match(html, @"books \\u0026 literature", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```